# ColdFusion server running, XAMPP running, but browsing to URL http://localhost/coldfusion/cfusion/wwwroot/variable.cfml shows CFML source?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, cfml

As the title states, Apache server is running, localhost is available, ColdFusion server is running when I check `Get-Service` in a terminal on Windows 10.  Apache runs on port 80, and the ColdFusion server runs on port 8581. So why is it that I see CFML source code and not the *processed* CFML when I go to where my file is saved at http://localhost/coldfusion/cfusion/wwwroot/variable.cfml?

Comment: ah http://127.0.0.1:8500/variable.cfml is the correct URL.  I am a tool. Thanks for those that at least looked  I appreciate it :) Although I would love some clarification if any one is there to offer it?

Comment: You are very likely running a webserver locally that is responding on Port 80 (the default HTTP port). So when you browse to `http://localhost/coldfusion/cfusion/wwwroot/variable.cfml`, it will be served through the regular webserver, which doesn't know how to deal with a  .cfm file. So it treats it like a text file and you see code.

Answer (score 3):

`127.0.0.1:8500/variable.cfml` is the correct URL. Thanks for those that at least looked I appreciate it :) Although I would love some clarification if any one is there to offer it? The basic trouble shooting page on Adobe was quite helpful....

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/basic-troubleshooting-and-faqs.html